# Excel: replacing an abbreviation with a string of text

Tags: excel-formula

I'm having trouble with using replace/substitute to auto replace an abbreviation with lines of text.

To make it easier for my crews to input their work, simply typing "wc" should be autofilling as "White Can 20L 308728"

We have various products with product codes to input but everything I'm finding references an already existing cell or replaces already existing text.

Comment: You can implement this with a custom *Spelling Correction* or a VBA Event macro.  Which do you prefer ?

Comment: You can do this with the [Find & Replace dialog](https://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/excel/how-to-use-excel-2010s-find-and-replace-feature/) (just hit `Ctrl+H`) or with the [`SUBSTITUTE` worksheet function](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-substitute-function) or with [VBA's `Replace` function](https://docs.microsoft.com/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/replace-function), and a few other ways. What specifically do you need help with? Also, be sure to check out the [tour] (you'll earn your first badge!) as well as "[ask]" and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: As @Gary said - you could use the _AutoCorrect Options_ found in _Options ~ Proofing_.  This will automatically change _wc_ to _White Can...._ - it will also change "Where is the wc?" to "Where is the Water Can..?"  It will only change it on the one computer, but the auto correct files can be found in the `%AppData%\Microsoft\Office` folder (`.acl` files) - could try just copying them to other computers/profiles.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion is to tabulate these products with their product codes and apply a `VLOOKUP` function to return the appropriate product description when a user types in a certain code. Limitation of this would be that the cell in which the worker would type in a code would not be the same cell that returns the appropriate product description for that code.

So assuming you have your list of product codes and description in Sheet2 - columns A (it is essential that this should be the product codes) and B (product description), and you want the formula to run in sheet1, you can use the following formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!$A:$B,2,0)
```

This assumes that you'll be encoding your code in cell A1 of Sheet1 (or any sheet other than your reference sheet).